# assign parts of struct to another struct in c

Tags: c++, c, struct

I want something conceptually like this in c/c++

```
struct first{
   int a,b,c;
}my1;

struct second{
   int a,b,c;
   int extended;
}my2;
```

and somehow be able to have

```
my2=my1;
```

(meaning only copy the same parts. leaving extended untouched)

I thought of solving it as

```
struct second{
     first first_;
     int extended;
 }my2;
```

and have

```
my2.first_ = my1;
```

but it is a bit ugly for me. is there any more clear solution for this?
probably it is something like extending a structure or something?

Comment: C or C++, or the common subset of both?

Comment: You somehow have to specify the the thing you want assigned-to, and the part of that thing you want modified.  So your solution is about as concise as it can get.  (The "_" is ugly indeed, but you can pick a different name to fix that).

Comment: If you want to do it in C++ then grab your C++ book and read about Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator.

Comment: I am more intrested in C as I want to later copy memoris assigned to these for cuda program. I am frightened that c++ might introduced additional memory overhead which might not get trapped in moving data.(just thinking)
I also saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807138/can-i-access-a-struct-inside-of-a-struct-without-using-the-dot-operator?rq=1 which gives similar answer to use 
    struct second: public first{ int extended};
but still for assignment I cant do my2=my1

Comment: Update the question to be only about C then

Comment: You can use `memcpy` `memcpy(&second, &first, sizeof(first));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
struct second : first
{
    int extended;

    second& operator=(const first& f)
    {
        first::operator=(f); extended = 0; return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: this looks great. can you explain code inside { }. what does first::operator=(f) does?

Comment: @Soren Right, thanks. Which brings the issue of what is `extended`'s default value, which is a constructor's job... anyway, let's say it's `0`.

Comment: @RoozbehG `first::operator=(f)` does whatever this (`second`) object seen as `first` would do when assigned another `first` `f`; that is, implicitly assign its `a,b,c` members the corresponding values from `f`.

Comment: no need to override `operator=`: just use `*(first*)&object = value;`, which works for both C and C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator The question had a `c++` tag (also in title) that was later removed. I wouldn't even be looking at questions about C.

Comment: @iavr: Yes, it also had a C++ tag, which is why I didn't say anything against your answer using C++. Still, it should have been useable for both imho, as both tags were there, now that you remind me.

Comment: @Deduplicator I will delete my answer in a few minutes then.

Comment: @iavr: Just add a bit for C then, and incorporate these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat equally ugly, but here it is :

```
my1 = *(first*)&my2;
```

Comment: I think I can use this too. but could it be somehow possible that compiler generate some paddings differently between my1 and my2 variables so their memory sizes dont match and this fails?

Comment: @Roozbeh G, it could. However, there is another rule that if two structs with a common initial sequence are both members of a union, then it is OK to alias the common iniital sequence.  So if you include the code `union X { struct first f; struct second g; };` then it guarantees that Flibustier's suggestion works even though you never instantiate that union.  AFAIK there are no implementations that would use a different structure if the union were not present, so people tend to just omit it and assume the compiler is not perverse.

Comment: @Matt What about the other way round `my2 = *(second*)&my1;` ? My assumption is you can't since sizeof(my2) > sizeof(my1).

Comment: Yeah that would access memory you don't own.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the `=` operator for `struct second`:

```
second & operator=(const first & s) {
    this->a = s.a;
    this->b = s.b;
    this->c = s.c;
    return *this;
}
```